# Python Capitalization elements in a list (using Itertools?)

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list containing integers which indicate how many capitalization will occur at once in a list.

```
x = [1, 2]
# when x == 1 then 1 capitalization per time
# when x == 2 then 2 capitalization per time
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

the output would be like so...

```
Abc
aBc
abC
ABc
AbC
aBC
```

I can code this normally, but can it be done through itertools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to pick the indices of the letters to capitalize:

```
from itertools import combinations


x = [1, 2]
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']


for xi in x:
    for comb in combinations(range(len(l)), xi):
        print("".join([e.upper() if i in comb else e for i, e in enumerate(l) ]))
```

**Output**

```
Abc
aBc
abC
ABc
AbC
aBC
```